# Can't vote or flag in full site on mobile Firefox

Tags: bug, mobile-firefox, full-site

This used to work, but as of several weeks ago, stopped. I noticed on [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com) first but it's not just limited to that.

If I click on

- upvote or downvote,
- upvote comment, or
- flag comment,

nothing happens.

Switching to the mobile theme makes it work, but then I can't tell what site I'm on at a glance, and on Photography, I loose the photo of the week header, *and* I'm missing other functionality.

FWIW, everything seems fine in Chrome on the same phone.

I don't think it's due to the hotspot being very small. Sometimes, apparently at random (and very rarely), it *does* work, but I can't replicate by very carefully hitting the same spot. Also, zooming in and very carefully going over the whole button doesn't help.

Comment: As mentioned in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21607/2687, this is due to the hotspot being very, very small for some reason. The strange thing is, the upvote/downvote buttons are actual links (`<a>`), so you'd think browsers would treat them as hotspots automatically.

Comment: If you say it's new behaviour "as of several weeks ago", I'm tempted to roll back to a previous version of Android Firefox (if available) and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely something that's changed. I'm not sure how easy it is to try old versions — my phone's not rooted and the stock app distribution methods certainly don't make that easy.

Comment: I usually use adb to sideload apps. (I don't root my phone either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, well, as of now, it's working again. Not sure if it was something on the Stack Exchange side or a Firefox update (42.0.2).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the reminder.